# Can't find the reason for this NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exception

I have the following method:

```
internal static void removeMethodFromTag(byte p, Method method)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Remove method " + method.getName() + " from the tag");
            List<Method> outList = new List<Method>();
            methodTaggings.TryGetValue(p, out outList);
            Console.WriteLine(outList.Count);
            outList.Remove(method);
            methodTaggings.Remove(p);
            methodTaggings.Add(p, outList);
        }
```

This is the dictionarry methodTaggings:

```
private static Dictionary<byte, List<Method>> methodTaggings = new Dictionary<byte, List<Method>>();
```

Now I always get a `NullReferenceException` in the line

```
Console.WriteLine(outList.Count);
```

But I can't see why? Even if I don't find a value in the dictionnary, the list shouldn't be null?

Comment: I can tell you that it seems possible that `outList` is set to `null`. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) says: "if the key is found; otherwise, the default value for the type of the value parameter.". And the default type of a list is `null`. Don't know for sure though.

Comment: Ah thanks, I always thought the list wouldn't just contain any element.

Comment: You can setup Visual Studio to break on Throw for NullReferenceException immediately. Then you will have a break in the line which caused the NullReferenceException and can debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should this not be:

```
internal static void removeMethodFromTag(byte p, Method method)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Remove method " + method.getName() + " from the tag");
            List<Method> outList = new List<Method>();
            if (methodTaggings.TryGetValue(p, out outList);
            {
              Console.WriteLine(outList.Count);
              outList.Remove(method);
              methodTaggings.Remove(p);
              methodTaggings.Add(p, outList);
           }
        }
```

Comment: NO! MethodTaggings can contain null valued outList for p parameter, so the problem won't be fixed!!!

Answer (score 2):

Add an if at the TryGetValue method. I think the TryGetValue is setting the out variable to null when it fails.

```
internal static void removeMethodFromTag(byte p, Method method)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Remove method " + method.getName() + " from the tag");
            List<Method> outList = new List<Method>();
            if(methodTaggings.TryGetValue(p, out outList)) {
                Console.WriteLine(outList.Count);
                outList.Remove(method);
                methodTaggings.Remove(p);
                methodTaggings.Add(p, outList);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The only suspect I can see here is this line:

```
methodTaggings.TryGetValue(p, out outList);
```

Could it be that `methodTaggings.TryGetValue` for the parameter `p` actually set outList to `null`?

Place a breakpoint on this line, and I think you will see that after you have stepped over this line, outList will be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

It can be initialized to `null` by the algorithm of `TryGetValue`. `out` paramters are always initialized insed method that is called.
And your code does not need this line:

```
List<Method> outList = new List<Method>();
```

If you use some method that would need ref (not out) parameter, than you would need it. But here out. 
Refer: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/UsingtheoutParameter12232005041002AM/UsingtheoutParameter.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to allocate the `outList` in your code, as you are passing it to `TryGetValue()` through its 2nd argument, which is declared as an [`out` parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645764%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

My guess is that `TryGetValue()` assigns `null` to `outList`.

Answer (score 1):

TryGetValue is replacing your outList with its default value *null*

Answer (score 1):

The value of the list will no longer there, no matter `TryGetValue` is successful or not, even you have assigned value to it before calling. A simple example:

```
int num = 9;
int.TryParse("abc", out num);
```

The `TryParse` is failed obviously, while the original value 9 will not be kept.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is when you call TryGetValue. Parameter `outList` is marked `out`, so your original empty list is lost there.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx):

> If the key is not found, then the value parameter gets the appropriate default value for the value type TValue; for example, 0 (zero) for integer types, false for Boolean types, and null for reference types.

And `List<Method>` is a reference type so it'll return `null`.

Good luck!